# Vue Component control Component instance variable by another same Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

So here I have a situation actually i am creating a popup on menu item. and popup is a component. So what i wanna achieve is to change the variable isOpen to false when another instance of component itself is called. let say for example

if menu item 1 is clicked popup component opens ( isOpen = true )
if menu item 2 is clicked popup component opens ( isOpen = true )

so this time there are two same component opens here if first one is clicked, second component should be automatically closed. but i can't figure it out that how can i change the popup.vue(component) variable isOpen is second popup component is clicked.

The issue is attached in the Sanbox Demo have a look.
[Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-stallman-4by3jr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is your state is stored in the popups instead of the component that holds the popups

For example:

```
<popup v-model='pop1' />
<popup v-model='pop2' />

watch(pop1, value => {
 if (value) pop2 = false
})
```

With that said, you can workaround by having your popups emit an open event.  When the parent receives this, it can close the other popup.

```
<popup ref='pop1' @open='$refs.pop2.close()' />
<popup ref='pop2' />
```

With many menus, it will be best to have a `currentMenu` property you set.  When a new menu opens, you update the current member.

```
<popup ref='pop1' :value='current==="p1"' @open='current="p1"' />
<popup ref='pop2' :value='current==="p2"' @open='current="p2"' />
```

Comment: can you explain more with the currentMenu property with an small example?

Comment: I have solved the issue all thanks to you. i emit an event to parent and get the refs set on popups components and make the variable to false when the currentmenu to true and rest to false